# I want to add another condition which removes a user that has already liked a film

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function which allows a user to dislike a film. However the user can only exist in the list of likes/dislikes but not both

```
 addUserDislikes :: Title -> User -> [Film] -> [Film] 
 addUserDislikes title user db = [ if ti == title && elem user dislike == False then (ti, di, yr,like,dislike++ [user])else (ti, di, yr, like, dislike) | (ti, di, yr, like, dislike) <- db]
```

This function only adds the user to the list of Dislikes but does not remove it from list of likes how do I do this?

other info - The `Title` & `User` are `Strings`. `Like` and `Dislikes` are lists in the tuple `Film`.

Comment: Try `not foo` instead of `foo == False`. What is `[1,2,3] //[3,4]`? What is `filter (/=5) [4,5,6,8]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to accomplish this in a list comprehension is hardly the easiest, or more readable approach. Instead, consider defining a function that handles a single `Film`. If you have such a function, the overall function becomes a simple map:

```
addUserDislikes :: Title -> User -> [Film] -> [Film]
addUserDislikes title user = fmap $ dislikeFilm title user
```

You can define `dislikeFilm` as a stand-alone function, if you will, or alternatively define it using `let` or `where` in `addUserDislikes`. If you write the function as a stand-alone function, you could write it like this:

```
dislikeFilm title user film@(ti, di, yr, likes, dislikes) =
  if ti == title
    then (ti, di, yr, delete user likes, user : dislikes)
    else film
```

Notice that this function returns `film` unmodified if `title` doesn't match. If, on the other hand, the title matches, it *cons* `user` onto `dislikes`, and simultaneously removes if from `likes`. For that, it uses `delete` from `Data.List`.

Here's some examples:

```
*Q49336125> addUserDislikes "2010" "foo" []
[]

*Q49336125> addUserDislikes "2010" "foo" [("2010", "Peter Hyams", 1984, [], [])]
[("2010","Peter Hyams",1984,[],["foo"])]

*Q49336125> addUserDislikes "2010" "foo" [("2010", "Peter Hyams", 1984, ["foo"], [])]
[("2010","Peter Hyams",1984,[],["foo"])]

*Q49336125> addUserDislikes "2010" "foo" [
    ("2010", "Peter Hyams", 1984, ["foo"], ["bar"]),
    ("2001", "Stanley Kubrick", 1968, ["baz", "qux"], [])]
[("2010","Peter Hyams",1984,[],["foo","bar"]),
 ("2001","Stanley Kubrick",1968,["baz","qux"],[])]
```

(Last evaluation hand-edited by me to make it more readable.)

(P.S. I liked both *2001* and *2010*, but I wanted to use some short film titles.)