# Haskell: Recursive function that puts only part of the students in a list

Tags: database, haskell, recursion

This is the data type:

```
data Student = Student String Int [String] [String]
   deriving (Show,Read)
```

This is my database:

```
db :: [Student]
db = [  
       Student "JenDavis" 54 ["Physics", "Maths"] ["Biology", "English"],
       Student "BenBlue" 62 ["Art", "English"] ["Maths", "PE"]          ,
       Student "JaydenBrimes" 56 ["Chemistry", "PE"] ["Music", "Maths"]
     ]
```

Currently, the function will add the inputted subject into the liked subjects list, if the studentname is matched in the student data, and if the liked subject is not already in the list. Then it returns the database from there to the end, not any of the data pieces before.

Function that only puts part of the students in a list:

```
likedNewSubject :: String -> String -> [Student] -> [Student]
likedNewSubject newSubject studName [] = []
likedNewSubject newSubject studName ((Student n g lk dl):students)
     | (n == studName) && (newSubject `notElem` lk) = (Student n g liked dl):students ++ likedNewSubject newSubject studName students
     | otherwise = likedNewSubject newSubject studName students
     where liked = newSubject:lk
```

How do I make the function add all students to the database without duplicates?

At the moment it only works if I use the student `"JenDavis"`.
If "BenBlue" likes a subject it will only return the student data of `"BenBlue"` and `"JaydenBrimes"`, not `"JenDavis"`. Thank you

I've tried this:

```
likedNewSubjectt :: String -> String -> [Student] -> [Student]
likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName [] = []
likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName ((Student n g lk dl):students)
    | (n == studName) && (newSubject `elem` lk) = (Student n g lk dl):students ++ likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName students
    | (n == studName) && (newSubject `notElem` lk) = (Student n g lk dl):students ++ likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName students
    | otherwise = likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName students
    where liked = newSubject:lk
```

which does the same thing

I've tried this:

```
likedNewSubjectt :: String -> String -> [Student] -> [Student]
likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName [] = []
likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName ((Student n g lk dl):students)
    | (n /= studName) = (Student n g lk dl):students ++ likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName students
dl):students ++ likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName students
    | (n == studName) && (newSubject `notElem` lk) = (Student n g lk dl):students ++ likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName students
    | otherwise = likedNewSubjectt newSubject studName students
    where liked = newSubject:lk
```

which does put everything in a list but has duplicates, and doesn't add the liked subject to the list.

I feel like it's supposed to be a really easy solution but I haven't seen it before, therefore I don't know what it looks like! I've also tried using

`` | (Student n g lk dl) `notElem` students = (Student n g lk dl):students ``

but it gives out an Eq error. I appreciate it.

`likedNewSubject :: String -> String -> [Student] -> [Student]
likedNewSubject newSubject studName [] = []
likedNewSubject newSubject studName ((Student n g lk dl):students)
     | (n == studName) && (newSubject`notElem`lk) = (Student n g liked dl):students ++ likedNewSubject newSubject studName students
     | ((Student n g lk dl)`notElem`students) = (Student n g liked dl):students
     | otherwise = likedNewSubject newSubject studName students
     where liked = newSubject:lk`

This is the eq error given from the function above.

[image: eq error given after inputting code above]

Comment: What attempts have you made to write a function that does this? Please write them in your question.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49336125/126014 The names are different, but the data types and the problem statement are equivalent.

Comment: That's interesting but I would really like to know a solution to my recursion problem. Understanding recursion completely would be really beneficial for me.

Comment: Adding a student to an empty database should produce a non-empty database, no (or at least acknowledge the attempt to update a non-existent student)? Check your base case.

Comment: Hello chepner thanks for replying, I don't understand what you mean. If I run the function I would use `likedNewSubject "PE" "JenDavis" db` which would then work perfectly because JenDavis is the first piece of data in db. If I did `likedNewSubject "Geography" "JaydenBrimes"` db, it will only put his data in the database, nobody else's.
My base case is there so if an empty database is given it will just return it as empty, but it should never be returning an empty database as I am always giving it db.

Comment: I would ask my lecturer but it's the weekend so I feel bad emailing him about it. I'm just going to see them tomorrow anyway, but if anyone does know the answer I can quickly move on from this point. I'm just really stuck at the moment.